# local.ERROR: The file "C:\Users\...\public" cannot be opened. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0) Laravel 8

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api, video

I'm trying to send a video from react to laravel

In React i'm sending the video:

```
let form = new FormData();
       
        form.append("video_trailer", data?.videoTrailer[0]);

        
        SetLoading(true);
        let response = await Post("courses-main/create", form);
        SetLoading(false);
```

console.log(data.videoTrailer)

```
[File]
0: File
lastModified: 1639894260433
lastModifiedDate: Sun Dec 19 2021 03:11:00 GMT-0300 (Hora padrão de Brasília) {}
name: "pexels-pavel-danilyuk-5495892.mp4"
size: 2450081
type: "video/mp4"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

error in presented in laravel.log

```
local.ERROR: The file "C:\Users\alex6\Documents\GitHub\plataforma_ensino\plataforma-ensino-back\public" cannot be opened. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): The file \"C:\\Users\\alex6\\Documents\\GitHub\\plataforma_ensino\\plataforma-ensino-back\\public\" cannot be opened. at C:\\Users\\alex6\\Documents\\GitHub\\plataforma_ensino\\plataforma-ensino-back\\vendor\
yholm\\psr7\\src\\Factory\\Psr17Factory.php:51)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\Users\\alex6\\Documents\\GitHub\\plataforma_ensino\\plataforma-ensino-back\\vendor\\symfony\\psr-http-message-bridge\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory.php(114): Nyholm\\Psr7\\Factory\\Psr17Factory->createStreamFromFile('C:\\\\Users\\\\alex6\\\\...')
#1
```

this error only occurs when i append data?videoTrailer[0] in form, even though my courses-main/create controller (the controller called) is only a Log::info($request) like this

```
 public function Create(Request $request) {
        Log::info($request);
}
```

Comment: You might need to add the encoding type to allow for file uploads https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#sending_files_using_a_formdata_object

Comment: make sure that php settings upload_max_filesize, and post_max_size are big enough to hold the video file size

Answer (score 0):

Resolved
I had to change the variables upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in my php.ini file, in order to be big enough to hold the video file size